# Can I change order amount with Stripes PaymentIntent?

Tags: stripe-payments, applepay

Using PaymentIntent is there a way to modify the final charge as I do not want to hit my tax calculation service until the user clicks "Buy"? I will show an estimated tax amount but it could change slightly.

Passing the PaymentIntent client_secret seems to require a final amount at that moment. I see that I could create the PaymentIntent on the fly via ajax for regular credit cards but not so sure about Apple Pay and Google Pay. Anyone found a way to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

If the PaymentIntent hasn't been cancelled or confirmed, you can update the amount [via the API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/update#update_payment_intent-amount).

Presuming you're using the Payment Request button for Apple Pay, you'd either [create the PaymentIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button#html-js-create-payment) with the exact amount including taxes or update it in the same way as above.

Comment: So it looks like I can just ajax in the Payment intent here: paymentRequest.on('paymentmethod', function(ev) {//Get the clientSecret}. Will Apple care that the amount changes? The PaymentIntent is from the server whereas creating the paymentRequest with an amount was client side? I would assume the PaymentIntent has priority.

Comment: If you're using the PaymentRequest button you should provide Apple/Google with the exact amount you intend to charge. I'd rework your flow so that you pass the total amount including taxes when creating the PaymentRequest object.

Comment: I'd like to but I am trying to avoid hitting my tax service before I get a commitment from the user. The tax service is a bit expensive for checkout abandoners. My estimated taxes are good but the final comes from a tax service. Will Apple or Google flag the payment if the amount changes(mostly in favor of the user)?

Comment: Charging an amount different to what was specified in the PaymentRequest object is possible from the Stripe side, but you should be ready to handle declines just in case. It seems to work for now but Apple/Google could change that at any time.